# How can i detect black circles with AForge (IsCircle Function) since it need an image with black backgroud?

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

I have an image of Go board with some stones. I need to detect these stone. I was trying [AForge's IsCircle Function](http://www.aforgenet.com/articles/shape_checker/)  but image's background have to be turn to black first. But I need to detect black circle.

Is it possible? or is there any other solution with other library (OpenCV)?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert black pixel to white pixel and white pixel to black pixel and then use Iscircle function to detect circle here is code to convert using Aforge.net

```
 Bitmap orig = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
            Bitmap clone = new Bitmap(orig.Width, orig.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(clone))
            {
                gr.DrawImage(orig, new Rectangle(0, 0, clone.Width, clone.Height));
          }

            FiltersSequence commonSeq = new FiltersSequence();
            commonSeq.Add(Grayscale.CommonAlgorithms.BT709);
            commonSeq.Add(new BradleyLocalThresholding());
            commonSeq.Add(new DifferenceEdgeDetector());

            Bitmap temp = commonSeq.Apply(clone);
```